# Opencv Rating Features in an Image

Tags: c++, opencv

The OpenCV forum has been unavailable for a few days so i am posting this questions here.  I want to implement a class in C++ that will analyze an image and determine how good that image is for feature tracking.

One approach has been explained by Vuforia.

https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Natural-Features-and-Ratings

1) Number of Features

Count the number of features returned, let's say requires min 30 features.

2) Local contrast

The variance can be used as a starting point to measure how much variation there is in the image. What sort of preprocessing would this require to get the most out of this metric?

How can we improve this? With a FT or DFT transform, would it be possible to see if there is high contrast at lots of different image frequencies? How would that be achieved?

DFT -> Variance   (?)

3) Feature distribution

This can be done with clustering, with a suitable center and mean+s.d. that is comparable to the image dimensions. 95% should be within mean + 2 x s.d. ideally.

4) Avoid organic shapes

This will yield no features, so is the same criteria as the number of features.

5) Avoid repetitive patterns

Match detected features against itself and make sure there aren't too many duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

**Vuforia** do the same .

***But if you want to write your own code to do the same then,***

- **ARToolkit** is open source SDK which provide same feature for NFT markers . if you go through the source code of ARToolkit then you
  will find something like **" DisplayFeatureSet"**
- There is **DisplayfeatureSet.exe** file also there which show the
  feature(Hotspots) of selected image like:

[image]

---

Somehow I managed to get source code(.c) for this. 
Here I providing My google Drive Link to download Source Code, Work on it and share your experience :

[Source Code to Display Feature Set](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6yyp13TrR5uc0xBYXJzR2dxTmM)

Best Luck :)

Comment: This is a nice approach, but it requires manual inspection. I am trying to automate the approach.

Comment: To automate it you required to count something like ratio of number of features get detected vs actual image size . Please chk the Link "Source Code " you can modify it . but it require deep knowledge of C. Im Java Developer :(